# Prevent (G)Vim from creating marks on its own

Tags: vim, vi

I just learnt about marks in Vim and I like it quite a lot. But I've noticed that Vim automatically creates marks, could there be a way to prevent that

Comment: Maybe you can provide an example of what you mean here.  Are you concerned about the jumplist?  About the '< and '> visual block marks?  You do realize that, by default, marks aren't saved to disk, right?

Comment: (Try giving an example of `:marklist` and call out the specific ones that concern you.)

Comment: Well the only problem I have is that I get loads of marks automatically created by vim, which I really don't need,

Comment: Ok, so many of them are for futures you don't (yet) use.  But how do they make your editing less efficient?

Comment: It's not that they make me less efficient... When they load, they take a mammoth amount of space when they open up, plus, when the file is loaded ( especially a large one ) it takes time to create marks. ( Or at least I think so... )

Comment: Marks aren't saved by default, at least in my vim.  If you have a viminfo file, you may have your configuration currently set to save marks.  I don't want to be a broken record, here, but could you take a look at `:marklist` and report which marks in it you feel are problematic?

Answer (score 0):

Some marks are set and updated automatically by Vim, others (like the named marks `a-z`) are available for you (though some plugins may use them for their purposes, too).

There's the `:delmarks` command, and you can control which and how many marks are persisted across Vim invocations via the `'viminfo'` configuration setting.